# Cant understand syntax of arduino sample code

Tags: c++, c, syntax, types, arduino

I'm trying to understand the sample code given for the MPU-9150 accelerator/gyroscope/magnometer. I imagine its quit basic but i haven't seen it before.

```
double dT = ( (double) MPU9150_readSensor(MPU9150_TEMP_OUT_L,MPU9150_TEMP_OUT_H) + 12412.0) / 340.0;
Serial.print(dT);
```

The `MPU9150_readSensor`relates to a function for receiving a 16bit integer from the sensor using the two addresses. What i don't understand is the `((double) MPU....`, why is this needed, hasnt it already been declared as a double?

Many thanks

Alex

Comment: It is not needed, the author made it explicit a conversion occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPU9150_readSensor()` returns an `int`.

we want the compiler to understand that you intentionally want a double value from the function.

that is why you type cast.

Reference: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-9150